# Using IF and Select tag | Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to set a value into the variable "counter" based on the option selected but it's not working, see my code below:

**HTML**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="data[0].dimension" class="form-control">
<option *ngFor="let data of dataopt" [value]="data.dimension">{{ data.dimension }}</option>
</select>
```

**TS**

```
data = [{
dimension: ''
}]

dataopt = [{dimension:'abc1'},
          {dimension:'abc2'},
          {dimension:'abc3'},
          {dimension:'abc4'}]

constructor(public graphicService: GraphicService) {
    this.graphicService.getDatas().subscribe(datas => {
  this.datas = datas;

  if (this.data[0].dimension == "abc1")
  {
    this.counter = 0;
  }
  else if(this.data[0].dimension == 'abc2'){
    this.counter = 2;
  }
  else{
    this.counter = 3;
  }
}}
```

And then I have a dynamic code based on the counter:

```
this.somedata[this.counter]
```

It's not working as expected

Comment: What happens and what did you expect would happen? What is it that is "not working"?

Comment: have you imported forms module in your compononent?

Comment: @Gustavo can you try with the code below

Answer (score 0):

if you have correctly imported FormsModule in your component then change your html and ts file like below

HTML

```
<select [(ngModel)]="dimensions" class="form-control" name="dimension">
<option *ngFor="let data of dataopt" [value]="data.dimension">{{ data.dimension }}</option>
</select>
```

no need to declare `data` as it is a local variable only.

TS

```
public dimensions: any;

dataopt = [{dimension:'abc1'},
          {dimension:'abc2'},
          {dimension:'abc3'},
          {dimension:'abc4'}]

constructor(public graphicService: GraphicService) {
    this.graphicService.getDatas().subscribe(datas => {
  this.datas = datas;

  if (this.dimensions == "abc1")
  {
    this.counter = 0;
  }
  else if(this.dimensions == 'abc2'){
    this.counter = 2;
  }
  else{
    this.counter = 3;
  }
}}
```